# Revenue By Month

Tags: apex, reporting, visualforce-charting

I am attempting to create a report that would provide me a month to month break down of revenue based on the opportunity's start date, end date and Estimated_Revenue and the calendar weeks. Given the start and end date, the calendar weeks are calculated as End Date - Start Date/ 7.

However, I still need to calculate revenue per day in a calendar week where our week consists of 5 days. Therefore, I am using the following formula to calculate

Revenue Per Week Per Day: Revenue/(End Date - Start Date/ 7)/5

Example: Start Date: 2014-08-03 End Date: 2014-12-12 Estimated_Revenue_Won: 185960.00

Revenue Per Week Per Day: 1987.35885447934559081471600

August: (2014-08-03 to 2014-08-31)* Revenue Per Day = 55646.04792542167654281204800
.... September: 57633.40677990102213362676400

How can I do something like this? Would this be via Apex Class, visualforce?

However, I do not know how to aggregate all this to get the desired result. I have been struggling with this for quiet a bit, any direction would be extremely helpful.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004526

Comment: Try checking out that link, it might help point you in the right direction. You need to try to separate the 5 weekdays from the weekends, but doing this may get weird around the first and last weeks. Hopefully this helps you figure out how to separate the two.

Comment: Thanks, I did take a look at that but I don't think this will be helpful. I need someone to essentially guide me through the process as to how this would be done in terms of Logic.